# Static variable as counter

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm writing a jQuery plugin and need to keep track of the number of objects on the page that utilize the plugin. Is there a way to create a static variable within the plugin that tracks instances of itself?

Here's what I have so far for the plugin:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.my_plugin = function (options)
    {
        var plugin_count = 0;

        return this.each(function() {
            alert(++plugin_count);
        });
    }
}(jQuery));
```

And on my page:

```
<div class="plugin_div"></div>
<div class="plugin_div"></div>
<div class="plugin_div"></div>
<div class="plugin_div"></div>

<script language="javascript">
    $('.plugin_div').my_plugin();
</script>
```

When the page loads, I get four alerts, with "1" displayed.

How can I write this so that the variable increments for each element that calls `my_plugin()`?

**EDIT:** Fixed bad copypaste job.

Comment: Your question is a little confusing: "... for each element that calls `my_plugin()`"; what does that mean?  Do you mean for each element that is affected by the plugin?  Each element that the plugin iterates over?  Each time the plugin is called at all?

Comment: I want to count the elements that utilize the plugin. Since I have 4 elements of class `plugin_div`, I want the counter to count to 4.

Comment: and then start at 5 the next time it's invoked?  Then all you really need to do is move the `var` declaration outside the plugin function (but inside the anonymous function).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.my_plugin = function (options)
    {
        $.fn.my_plugin.count = $.fn.my_plugin.count || 0;

        return this.each(function() {
            alert(++$.fn.my_plugin.count);
        });
    }
}(jQuery));
```

Or don't use the `$.fn` but `$.my_plugin.count` so you can also define defaults to your plugin as:

```
$.my_plugin = {
    count : 0,
    defaults : {}
};

// Extend options with plugin defaults!
$.extend(options, $.my_plugin.defaults);
```

Comment: This was such a simple answer, and so obvious. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript functions are first-class objects so you can store arbitrary properties on them, e.g. `$.fn.my_plugin.whatever`

Of course it would be even nicer if you could do this without repeating the function name - but `arguments.callee` is deprecated so you'll have to keep using the full function name.

Answer (score 0):

Just move the declaration of "plugin_count" to outside the function:

```
(function ($) {
    var plugin_count = 0;

    $.fn.my_plugin = function (options)
    {
        return this.each(function() {
            alert(++plugin_count);
        });
    }
}(jQuery));
```

That captures "plugin_count" in the closure formed by the outer anonymous function call. No need to maintain the count as the property of any explicit object, when the closure will do that for you.

Comment: @roXon ah sorry I just cut&pasted the OP code.  Also, what??  The `++` happens when the plugin is called, which is exactly what's desired, no?

Comment: @roXon the jsbin you linked correctly alerts "1", "2", "3", "4".  Now I admit that the question is not really clear as to what exactly is supposed to be counted. *edit* oh ha ha no worries.  I think the question is kind-of vague.